# What does 14/.3 mm in "PVC Insulated Copper Wire(14/.3mm)" mean?

Tags: wire

I thought it was a spelling mistake in my lab book but apparently they wire with that notation, what does it mean? is 14 mm the length and 0.3 mm the thickness of the wire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It usually means that the cable is made from 14 strands of wire with each wire having a diameter of 0.3 mm. This means it has an overall cross sectional area of 1 mm²: -

$$14\times \dfrac{\pi\cdot 0.3^2}{4} = 0.9896\text{ sq mm}$$

Example from [Farnell](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/71744.pdf): -

[image]